# C++ Array or Vector of template classes with different value-type template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, vector, value-type

One application needs to handle a set of datasets on which some operations can be performed. Each data set contains an array of points of a specific data type (int32, int16, float, complex) and the same operations can be performed on the data contained in each data set. For example a Fourier Transform or a Filter. So in the Data Model (used in the model-view-controller pattern), i wanted to store the collection of open data sets, each with his own data type.

Following [How to put different template types into one vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696399/how-to-put-different-template-types-into-one-vector), to put template classes with different type parameters can be used inheritance or boost variants.

I'd like to avoid the use of variants, and i would like to keep the value-type.

What i would like is to store a vector (if possible, an array would be better) of classes with different template parameters:

```
    template < typename T >
    class DataSet {
      private:
      T data;
      // ...
       public:
      T getData() {return data;}
    };

    std::vector< DataSet< something > > v;
    v.push_back( DataSet<int32_t*>() );
    v.push_back( DataSet<float*>()   );
    v.push_back( DataSet<int16_t*>() );
```

What's the right approach to do this? Or to handle a collection of objects with different value-types on which i can perform the same operations?

Comment: Your float data contains a bool.. If the types you want are simple and fixed, you could use a union.

Comment: *Why* do you need this? What is the usecase? There are often better solutions if you tell use the bigger problem your trying to solve, not only what you think you need to do to solve it.

Comment: That's right, thank you for the comment. I edited the question including the general problem.

Comment: The right approach really is a visitor pattern, and variant enables that easier.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a fixed range, you can use `boost::variant`, else consider `boost::any`.

Comment: yes, thank you! But i knew it and i wanted to know if it is possible to avoid it.

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this:

```
struct Base {};
template <class T> struct Data : public Base { T x; };
vector<Data*> elements;
elements.push_back(new Data<int>{3});
elements.push_back(new Data<char>{'a'});
```

The reason that a pointer is used is that all vector elements must have the same size, so we can't store the object directly, but are forced to use a pointer instead. You can then use `typeid` to query the type of an element

```
`if (typeid(*elements[0]) == typeid(Data<int>))`
```

This method incurs a runtime penalty though, just like the use of boost variants. If you know in advance what type each field will have, it may be wise to use a `tuple` instead.

Comment: Why no RAII? Did the question specify that?

Comment: @tohava if you don't use RAII, you should at least mention that care must be taken to ensure that everything is delete'd again.

Comment: Yes, my example shows that it is possible. They still need to be wrapped though.